# Heckscher-Ohlin with heterogeneous preferences

Tags: preferences, competitive-equilibrium

could someone really help me out I would need to show a situation in which the Heckscher-Ohlin result does not necessarily hold when preferences are heterogeneous. 
Does someone have an idea how I could do that?

Would really appreciate the support 
Cheers, 
James

Comment: What have you tried so far? E.g. did you try taking any random heterogeneous preferences + production coefficients and calculating the competitive equilibrium?

Comment: Not really, wouldn't know how to do that

Comment: How would I go about if i wanted to add production coefficients to calculate the competitive equilibirum? Thank you for being so active

Comment: That is a whole different question all together. In what situation would you need produce an example where the Hecksher-Ohlin result does not hold where you don't already know how to calculate the competitive equilibrium?